# Text is blurry ubuntu 22.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, text

So i recently switched to ubuntu. Everything works good and i love it! But there is a one problem that's been driving me crazy.  The text is not sharp on my external monitor(27 inch 1920 x 1080) but everything looks great on laptop's built-in screen(15.6 1920x1080). I've been searching the internet for two days and can't find a solution to make the text look sharp. I tried changing hinting to full but it's blurry. I didn't have this problem on Windows. The text is also blurry in JetBrains Rider and Firefox. Is there a way of fixing this or i just need to live with it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but after i switched to KDE from GNOME the fonts started to look great again. Ditched Ubuntu and switched to Kubuntu.